# Using an array in an Autofilter

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

rname is an array I initialized dynamically.

i am getting this in the vba code

> Run-Time Error '1004' : Application-defined or Object Defined error

```
For z=2 to lr2
    k=0
    if sh3.Cells(z,2)>1 Then
        size=sh3.Cells(z,2).value2-1
        Redim rname(size)
        Do While z<z+sh3.Cells(z,2).value2 And k<sh3.Cells(z,2).value2-1
            z=z+1
            rname(k)=sh3.Cells(z,1).value2
            k=k+1
        Loop
        With sh1.Range("A3")
            .AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1:= sh.Cells(x,2).value2
            .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=rname()
        End With
```

Comment: what is sh3? The code is looking for a worksheetsheet  with codename sh3.

Comment: @SJR: I could see that in the meantime... I will delete my comment.

Comment: How did you declare `rname` array?

Comment: Maybe "Criteria1:=rname() , Operator:=xlFilterValues" would help

Comment: @FaneDuru Dim rname() as String

Comment: Did you check if the array is loaded as expected?

Comment: Are there negative values in `sh3.Cells(z,2).value2`?

Comment: Try using `.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=rname` without the `()`

Answer (score 0):

I think your `AutoFilter` needs to know what `XlAutoFilterOperator` to use for your Criteria. Try, please modify it in:

```
.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=rname(), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```